# Xcode export XLIFF for development language

Tags: xcode, localization, xliff

When trying to export XLIFF for my development language there is no way to include translations.

I have a development language set to Czech like this

[image]

When I want to export existing translations for Czech - there is no checkbox for that

[image]

I can select 'Development Language Only' but it does not give me current translations I already have in Localizable.strings (Czech).

Everything is working fine for Slovak though. I also want to have Czech language to be a default one for English, France etc. That's why I set it up as a development language.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you come across any solution ?

Comment: No. I think that Apple is assuming that you have your development language translations as the keys in translations. So a key = translation for development language. Then you do not need such development language export.

Comment: That's not the best solution... What happens if I want to change an english text, but keep a translation? 
So I would have to change both ? That's a lot of extra work

Comment: Couple of notes. 1] I agree it's weird. Maybe we both are missing something. Localization for iOS was always a mystery for me. Just remember genstring.. 2] I wouldn't say it's a lot of overhead. Changing dev language key should not happen often + xliff export will make it very easy process to fix all the other languages.